# INVISIBLE unknown character when using Ser.readline() in python

Tags: user-interface, pyserial

I am working on a project to communicate between angle sensor (through micro) to the python GUI

I was trying to send a 2 byte's of  data from the micro controller through UART (~ ranges from 0-360 which exceeds 1 byte after 255)

This is how i am splitting the data and will combine them on the receiving side

```
angle = readangle();
send[0] = angle ;
send[1] = angle >> 8;
```

and coming back to python

```
self.ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200, timeout=0.05)
f = self.ser.readline(2)
.
.
.
.
x = ord(self.f[1])  
x = x << 8 | ord(self.f[0])  
self.angle = x   #  this updates the angle value in the GUI
```

its gives out he correct values almost all the times BUT !
the value suddenly points to zero which makes my GUI to take a deep dive  (once in every 30-50 samples )

```
%up0EEA$
³ 
iam here
³ 
179
%up0EEA$
³ 
iam here
³ 
179
.
.
.
%up0EEA$
Ê 
iam here
Ê 
202
%up0EEA$
ç 
iam here
ç 
231
%up0EEA$

iam here

257
%up0EEA$

iam here

261
%up0EEA$    
 Í         ---HERE ("Is that a white space before that ASCII " )  
iam here
 Í
0           
%up0EEA$
 ”
iam here
 ”         --- AGAIN !! 
0
%up0EEA$
î 
iam here
î 
238
```

AND NOW !!  i am struck on how to get rid of that fancy invisible character in my serial data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured that my code has many`self.ser.open()` and `self.ser.close()`

The command  `self.ser.flushInput()` solved my problem

```
f = self.ser.readline()
        self.ser.flushInput()
```